# nativeElement.classList.add() alternative

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to create a button component in angular 2.
At the host I have to set a dynamically generated css classname. (depending on binded property)

'[ngClass]' on host does not work.

I've read that using elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add(value) is not the best way either, because classList is not supported on webworkers (or so)

**What are my best options to generate the class dynamically on host?**

```
@Component({
    selector: '[md-button]',
})
export class MdButton {
    color_: string;

    @Input
    set color() {
        this.color_ = value;
        if (this.elementRef !== undefined) {
            this.elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add('md-' + this.color_);
        }   
    }

    get color(): string {
        return this.color_;
    }

    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef){}
}
```

Comment: `this.elementRef.nativeElement.className += ' md-' + this.color_` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@Component({
    selector: '[md-button]' //,
    // host: { '[class]': 'classList()' }
})
export class MdButton {
    color_: string;

    // classList() {
    //  return 'md-' + this.color_;
    // }

    @Input
    set color() {
        this.color_ = value;
        // if (this.elementRef !== undefined) {
        //    this.elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add('md-' + this.color_);
        // }   

        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elementRef, 'md-' + this.color_, true);
    }

    get color(): string {
        return this.color_;
    }

    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @günter-zöchbauer, but that leaves a problem. When try to set `<button md-button class="myCustomClass" color="accent">submit</button>`the class 'myCustomClass' is overriden by 'md-accent'. Both should exist.

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm not entirely sure if the `elementRef` or `elementRef.nativeElement` needs to be passed. In a recent updated it was changed for some/all APIs and I haven't checked since if `Renderer` is included but I think so.

Comment: Is this still the best way to do it? Renderer is deprecated. And can someone confirm what OP said about webworkers? Why is adding or removing from classlist a bad way?

Comment: The deprecation nodes in https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer says "Use the Renderer2 instead." which is mostly the same.

Comment: You can also use `elementRef.nativeElement...` and common JS code to modify the class of an element, if you don't care about server-side rendering or web-worker support.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to Günter I've found the solution.
This is his code but cleaned for anyone who can use it in the future.

```
private color_: string;

@Input()
set color(value: string) {
    this.color_ = value;

    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elementRef, 'md-' + this.color_, true);
}

get color(): string {
    return this.color_;
}

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { }
```