# How to get class attribute via renderer (or alternative) in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I've found an alternative for nativeElement.classList.add() in angular2.
(original question described here: [looking for nativeElement.classList.add() alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506395))

But now I want to get the class attribute before rendering the new one.
Because if the color value changes a new class is added, but the old one is not removed.

So I'm trying to resolve

```
<button md-button color="accent" class="myClass"></button>
```

to

```
<button md-button color="accent" class="myClass md-accent"></button>
```

When the color property changes to warn, it should render

```
<button md-button color="warn" class="myClass md-warn"></button>
```

For now it renders

```
<button md-button color="warn" class="myClass md-accent md-warn"></button>
```

So what I try to do is: before updating `this.color_`, remove the `md-this.color_` class .

```
@Input()
set color(value: string) {
    // READ CLASS ATTRIBUTE HERE, SO I CAN REMOVE THE OLD md-this.color_
    this.color_ = value;

    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elementRef, 'md-' + this.color_, true);
}
```

Getting the attribute through nativeElement is not an option because this doesn't work in webworkers.

Any idea's ?

Comment: Can't you just remove it by calling `this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elementRef, 'md-' + this.color_, false);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just need to remove it blindly with

```
this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'md-' + this.color_, false);
```

Comment: oh no... :-) Just that simple.

Comment: This removes indeed the class. But when it's the last class in the list, the class attribute remains empty on the element, wich is invalid html. This is a bug in Angular. Can the attribute be removed anyway in this case?

Comment: Seems there is no way. No matter which way you use to update the classes, Angular leaves the `class` when the last class is removed. A workaround would be to add some dummy class that you just ignore but prevents the list getting empty.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a old question, but since I landed here I thought I update it.

Not sure since when it's possible, but you can get the currently applied classes by

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.className
```