# Is it possible to add a dynamic class to host in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I know that in Angular2 I can add a class 'red' to a component's selector element by doing this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'selector-el',
    host: {
        '[class.red]': 'true'
    },
    ...
})
```

I'm wondering whether there's a way to add a *dynamic* class to a host, similar to what you would do with NgClass (I know NgClass is not actually supported, I'm looking for possible solutions):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'selector-el',
    host: {
        '[NgClass]': 'colorClass'
    },
    ...
})
...
constructor(){
    this.colorClass = 'red';
}
```

Comment: I actually meant to add that edit to my question (didn't realize I was on this Q). I can't seem to remove my edit.

Comment: @Kudla69 no problem, this has been handled. You can proceed to add it to your question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
@Directive({
  (...)
  host: {
    '[class.className]' : 'className', 
    '[class]' : 'classNames' 
  }
}
export class MyDirective {
  className: boolean;
  classNames: string;

  constructor() {
    this.className = true;
    this.classNames = 'class1 class2 class3';
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I suppose this supports ngStyle as well?

Comment: Although this is awesome, it's no longer the recommended approach https://angular.io/styleguide#style-06-03

Comment: Do you know how we can accomplish the same thing with the new recommendations?

Answer (score 22):

If you like to change it from outside you can combine `@HostBinding` and `@Input()`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: ``
})
export class MyComponent {
    @HostBinding('class.your-class') @Input() isSelected: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. The only way to work with changes coming from outside your component. Without the @Input(), changes made outside only reflect with a reload.

Comment: this appends global class, not local component class. If you need to use local component class define class as: `:host.your-class { ... }`

Answer (score 20):

The `Renderer`s `setElementClass` can be used to add or remove an arbitrary   class. For example `md-[color]` where `color` is provided by an input

```
<some-cmp [color]="red">
```

```
@Component({
// @Directive({
    selector: 'some-cmp',
    template: '...'
})
export class SomeComp {
    _color: string;

    @Input()
    set color(color: string) {
        this._color = color;
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'md-' + this._color, true);
    }

    get color(): string {
        return this._color;
    }

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){}
}
```

See also [nativeElement.classList.add() alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506395/looking-for-nativeelement-classlist-add-alternative)

Comment: I would like to point out, that you now need to pass the `nativeElement` to the renderer and not the `ElementRef`, for adding a class.

Comment: I had to use Renderer2 (see https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2). Also using `addClass(el, name)` is an option

Answer (score 9):

I did it in this way. Maybe someone will come in handy

```
@HostBinding('class') get hostClasses() {
    return `some-class ${this.dynamicOne} ${this.disabled ? 'disabled' : ''}`;
}
```

**OR Simon_Weaver's Suggestion: (`the return value can also be an array`, Thank you!)**

```
@HostBinding('class') get hostClasses() {
  const classList = ['some-class', this.dynamicOne];
  if( this.disabled) { classList.push('disabled'); }
  return classList;
}
```

Comment: the return value can also be an array

Answer (score 7):

```
import {Component, HostBinding} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  (...)
}

export class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding('class') colorClass = 'red';
}
```

Comment: How to update colorClass variable to some other value, say 'blue'

Comment: @manpreetsingh Just change the variable's value.  For instance, `this.colorClass = "blue";`

Answer (score 5):

I have recently made a directive called `<ng-host>` (inspired by [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19119)), it will redirect every (non-structural) change to the component host element, usage:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ng-host [ngClass]="{foo: true, bar: false}"></ng-host>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  `
})
class AppComponent { }
```

Online demo can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iutvor?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts).

Supported usages defined [here](https://github.com/trotyl/angular-contrib/blob/db86a98b4fe3f073ee5f20ee788a7e2aeb5448b1/packages/common/host/host.spec.ts#L125-L128).

<strike>I have achieved this by the **Directive as a Service** pattern, namely manually providing `NgClass` and use it like ([online demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pu7a9s?embed=1&file=app/hello.component.ts))</strike>

<strike>Due to the DI mechanism, `NgClass` will get the `ElementRef` of current host element, the `Self()` modifier helps to guarantee it. So no need to create an instance by constructor, thus still under public API usage.</strike>

<strike>It could be more concise when combined with class inheritance, an example can be found at [here](https://github.com/trotyl/ng-antd/blob/b5794650f39ef595745f53fed79c9a7280a4bbeb/src/lib/button/button.ts#L53-L61).</strike>

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    selector: "[textbox]",
    host: {"class": "first-class secondClass ThirdClass AnYClaSs"},
    template: ...                                            
})
export class MyComponent { }
```

Which is imo way more straightforward than introducing a variable.
**Should work in Angular2 rc5, rc6, rc7, final. May work in earlier versions, but didnt try it.**

Comment: The original poster was looking for **dynamic** assignment of classes; this is static, right?

Comment: Not helpful at all, again, not dynamic, as requested by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
import { Component, Attribute, HostBinding } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "selector-el",
    template: ...                                            
})
export class MyComponent {
    @HostBinding('class') get classAttribute(): string {
        let defaultClasses = 'selector-el-class';
        return defaultClasses + ' ' + this.classNames;
    }

    constructor(
        @Attribute('class') public classNames: string
    ) { }
}
```