# Passing in additional class names to an angular2 component

Tags: angular

I have a reusable component `ModalComponent` that already has the class name `.Modal` attached via:

```
@HostBinding('attr.class') className = `Modal`;
```

I know we can pass in data through inputs making the following possible:

```
@Input() additionalClass;
```

But this does not work as expected:

```
@HostBinding('attr.class') className = this.additionalClass ? `Modal ${this.additionalClass}` : 'Modal';
```

What is the best way to pass in *additional* class names to an Angular2 component?

**Edit:**

I've come up with this solution, however, it seems pretty dense considering the nature of the issue. Can anyone confirm that this is the correct way to accomplish this?

```
@Input() className: string;
@HostBinding('class') extraClasses;
@HostBinding('class.Modal') baseClass;

constructor() {
  this.baseClass = true;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.extraClasses = this.className;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="modal {{additionalClass}}"></div>`
you can set it like this,so div will have a class modal always and if 'additional class' is provided, it will also appear as a class else div will only have class 'modal'.

Comment: While this would work for a child of `ModalComponent` in the template, it doesn't work for the component its self. It has to essentially be `<modal class="Modal {{additionalClass}}"></modal>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35996212/is-it-possible-to-add-a-dynamic-class-to-host-in-angular-2
if that is the case, this might be what you are looking for.